# EntityFramework : Check if the Integer relationship is null

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, mapping

I have to get roots of some tree but
The EF query:

```
SomeTree.Where(t => t.ParentID == null);
```

Or Dynamic linq query:

```
SomeTree.Where("ParentID== null");
```

returns the `sql` query:

```
SELECT 
CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C1], 
CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
WHERE 1 = 0
```

Why it doesn't return roots?

the mapping:

```
            HasKey(c => c.ID);
            Property(c => c.ID).HasColumnName("ACTID").HasColumnType("int").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
            Property(c => c.Title).HasColumnName("ACTName").HasColumnType("nvarchar").HasMaxLength(100).IsUnicode(true).IsVariableLength().IsRequired();
            Property(c => c.ParentID).HasColumnName("ACTActKindID").HasColumnType("int").IsOptional();            
            HasMany(c => c.Children).WithRequired(c => c.Parent).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE 1 = 0
```

looks pretty bad, (IE this wont ever return)

I would guess that your parentID column in the database isnt nullable

Comment: Its Nullable but the problem is the mapping